# What socket and terminals do I need to buy for this plug?

Tags: connector

I have a "coin mechanism" from a fruit machine that I want to connect up. It has two plugs. One is 17 pins and one is 22 pins. The connections are the 2.54mm connectors and the instructions say I need a "17 Way Molex SIL 6471" connector.

[image: 17 pin socket]

For the 22 pin plug I have the correct socket but don't have the tools or the crimps in order to add any more wires to it.

[image: 22 pin socket]

Here is the correct socket for the 22 pin plug.

[image: 22 pin plug]

And here is the connections from one on of the links inside the plug.

[image: Link]

I did a LOT of Googling and also asked on here and managed to find these sockets from RS.

[image: New socket]

These sockets fit the slot after I snip off the small plastic 'keys' at the edges but I don't think I've bought the correct crimps.

These are the crimps I bought that I thought would be needed.

[image: Crimp]

But these crimps don't seem to suit the socket I've got.

Do you know what socket and terminals/crimps that I need to do this job properly?

A big thank you for any help you can give me and if you need more information please ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the Amphenol 17 way MIN-PV series housing (part number 65039-020LF):

[image]

with the appropriate crimp connector depending on size (47711-001LF for 28-32awg, 47712-001LF for 22-26awg and 47713-001LF for 18-20awg):
[image]

and if you really want to do the job properly, add the little polarising plug to the housing to match up with the missing pin (65307-001LF):

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your excellent answer. I don't suppose you would know whether it is possible to buy "pre-wired" crimps? I don't have the specific crimp tool needed and they are in the hundreds of pounds? Thanks again for your excellent clear description. It is much appreciated :)

Comment: I've soldered these terminals in the past. I suspect you could find a cheaper crimp tool to do the job but I've not seen pre-crimped wires. If you need a lot I'm sure there will be a company happy to make them.

Comment: Thanks again. I only need 21 of these so I'll maybe enquire on a hobbyist forum to see if someone would make them up and send them me for a fee. Thanks again for all your help. :)